# how to validate html code

Tags: html, css

i want to check the mistake  of  our html code.
are you suggest me  some method in firefox to improve mark up code and solve old code mistake.

How to edit the html. who give me error list node by node like a ul is missing etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Firefox addon:**

**[HTML Validator](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/249/)**

**W3C:**

**[W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/)**

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to look at the Web Developer Toolkit and Firebug plugins. Between them you can do just about anything you need to do in terms of debugging html and css.

Comment: The Web Developer is awesome!

Answer (score 2):

HI,
You should use firebug for this will help to developer to know about error or mistake.
and

http://validator.w3.org/ is also help to know mistakes and some software as dreamweaver and notepad++ will help.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 0):

You're after this: http://validator.w3.org/.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're referring to specifically.  If you're talking about W3C validation you can access the validator tool [here](http://validator.w3.org/).

If something isn't displaying right you could install firebug (Firefox addon) to see what's happening, though this is more of a CSS issue than html.

Without knowing the specifics of your problem it is hard to give more specific advice than that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java on the server side, you can add the [JTidy servlet](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/multiproject/jtidyservlet/index.html) to your web.xml to validate all HTML generated by your web application.